# Formulating an efficient DB query with highly challenging requirements (Django app)

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql, query-optimization

This is a tough one. I have a django-based web-app where users can post interesting URLs, and have spectators comment under each posting. Moreover, I use [stealth banning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_banning) against misbehaving users.

Interesting URLs are represented by `Link` model; comments under the posting are reprenseted by `Publicreply` model.

Here's how these models are related to one other:

```
class Link(models.Model): 
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250)

class Publicreply(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])
```

`Users` I ban go here:

```
class HellBanList(models.Model):
    condemned = models.ForeignKey(User)
    when = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What's my question? I'm trying to write the **best performing**, **optimized query** that gets me:

**1.** The `publicreply` with the absolutely **latest timestamp** FROM among all distinct `links` THAT either the user herself posted, OR below which the said user left a `publicreply`

**2.** But if the `publicreply` object gotten in 1 was of someone who's part of `HellBanList` (i.e. condemned attribute), I'd want to ignore that particular `publicreply` and dig up the next *most-recent one*. If that's of a banned user too, I'll skip to the next (and so on).

**3.** Finally, I only need `submitted_by` and `submitted_on` attribute values from the `publicreply` object I end up with after catering for both 1 and 2.

---

So what have I tried thus far? This:

```
freshest_link = Link.objects.filter(Q(submitter=self.request.user)|Q(publicreply__submitted_by=self.request.user)).distinct().annotate(date=Max('publicreply__submitted_on')).latest('date')
freshest_reply = Publicreply.objects.filter(answer_to=freshest_link).latest('submitted_by')
```

What's the problem with this code? The fact that it doesn't cater to requirement **2**. I think I ought to have somehow run an `exclude()` on `publicreplys` posted by `users` in `HellBanList` **before** calculating `freshest_reply` (in order to meet requirement **2**). Anyhow I can't figure out how to do that. Secondly, an expert can perhaps build the whole query more efficiently than how I've attempted it, goal being minimum possible DB roundtrips.

Can you help out in this? If you feel I've been opaque in my description of what I'm trying to achieve, do ask for clarification.

*Note: my DB is postgres*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the banned users list like:

```
banlist = HellBanList.objects.values_list('condemned',flat=True)
```

modify freshest_reply query like:

```
freshest_reply = Publicreply.objects.filter(answer_to=freshest_link).exclude(submitted_by_id__in=banlist).latest('submitted_on')
```

**2nd method:**

In your query, first you get the `Link` which has the latest public reply and in the next query you get the latest `Publicreply` for that `Link`. Instead of that we can just get the latest reply in one query like:

```
latest_reply = Publicreply.objects.filter(Q(answer_to__submitter=self.request.user)|Q(submitted_by=self.request.user)).exclude(submitted_by_id__in=banlist).latest('submitted_on')
```

Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Great, Anush! The 2nd method especially profiles very nicely (I added one more exclude() - for self.request.user - but that wasn't in the reqs, so no worries). Thanks for chiming in buddy. I also have another reply from you I have yet to test and accept. Soon!